# Getting Error While Uploading in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, php

```
$_FILES array is empty
```

getting this error whenever try to upload an image have tested everything even changing a server and also updated the Magento 2 version but the issue is still the same.
Magneto V 2.3.7

Answer (score 0):

Can you try below code and check,

1. In your form, add the **`enctype`** attribute to the **`<form>`** tag:

Here is the code:-

```
<form action="your/controller/action" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <!-- Your form fields go here -->
    <input type="file" name="file_field_name">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload">
</form>
```

2. In your controller, use the **`$_FILES`** array to retrieve the uploaded file:

Here is the code:-

```
<?php
namespace YourVendor\Module\Controller\YourController;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;

class YourAction extends Action
{
    public function execute()
    {
        $file = $_FILES['file_field_name'];
        // Do something with the uploaded file
    }
}
```

Let me know if any query.

**`THANKS.`**